# Is there any theory pertaining to an assumption to would allow the following inequality to hold (constrained LASSO)

Tags: lasso, high-dimensional, inequality

Suppose we observe the vector-matrix pair $(y,\mathbf{X})\in\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^{n\times d} $ which is linked by the observation model:
\begin{equation}
y=\mathbf{X}\theta^*+\epsilon 
\end{equation}
where $\epsilon\in \mathbb{R}^n$ is the noise vector. In this setting the constrained LASSO is expressed as follows:
\begin{equation}
\hat{\theta}=\min_{\theta \in \mathbb{R}^d}\left\{\frac{1}{2n}\lVert y-\mathbf{X}\theta\rVert_2^2 \right\},\quad\text{such that} \lVert \theta \rVert_1 \leq R
\end{equation}
for some radius $R>0$.

Since $\hat{\theta}$ is optimal, from the theory of M-estimators, we have $\frac{1}{2n}\lVert y-\mathbf{X}\hat{\theta}\rVert_2^2 \leq \frac{1}{2n}\lVert y-\mathbf{X}\theta^*\rVert_2^2$, which with some basic algebraic manipulation:
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{1}{2n}\lVert y-\mathbf{X}\hat{\theta}\rVert_2^2 &\leq& \frac{1}{2n}\lVert y-\mathbf{X}\theta^*\rVert_2^2\\
\frac{1}{2n}\lVert y-\mathbf{X}\theta^*+\mathbf{X}\theta^*-\mathbf{X}\hat{\theta}\rVert _2^2&\leq& \frac{1}{2n}\lVert \epsilon\rVert_2^2\\
\frac{1}{2n}\lVert \epsilon-\mathbf{X}\hat{\Delta}\rVert_2^2&\leq& \frac{1}{2n}\lVert \epsilon\rVert_2^2\\
\frac{1}{2n}\lVert \epsilon\rVert_2^2-\frac{1}{n}\epsilon^{\top}\mathbf{X}\hat{\Delta}+\frac{1}{2n}\lVert \mathbf{X}\hat{\Delta}\rVert_2^2&\leq& \frac{1}{2n}\lVert \epsilon\rVert_2^2
\end{eqnarray}
which leads to the *basic inequality*:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\lVert\mathbf{X}\hat{\Delta}\rVert_2^2}{n}\leq\frac{2\epsilon^{\top}\mathbf{X}\hat{\Delta}}{n}
\end{equation}

Now suppose I have a matrix $\mathbf{X}^c \in \mathbb{R}^{(n-1)\times d}$, where now essentially
\begin{equation}
\lVert \mathbf{X}\hat{\Delta}\rVert=\lVert \mathbf{X}^c\hat{\Delta}\rVert+(x_n^{\top}\hat{\Delta})^2
\end{equation}
where $x_n$ is the last row of matrix $\mathbf{X}$. Given that $\hat{\Delta}:=\hat{\theta}-\theta^*$ and $\hat{\theta}$ is the optimal estimator for *all* $n$ observations, can under certain conditions and assumptions the below claim also be made?

\begin{equation}
\frac{\lVert\mathbf{X}^c\hat{\Delta}\rVert_2^2}{n-1}\underbrace{\leq}_{?}\frac{2\epsilon^{c\top}\mathbf{X}^c\hat{\Delta}}{n-1}
\end{equation}
where $\epsilon^c\in\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$.

Comment: What is $\theta^\star$? What is the expression $\frac{1}{2n}\lVert y-\mathbf{X}\hat{\theta}\rVert_2^2 \leq \frac{1}{2n}\lVert y-\mathbf{X}\theta^*\rVert_2^2$ relating to, the expected norm, the norm in a particular sample? It make no sense to me that such inequality holds. What if $R \approx 0$, then $\hat\theta \approx 0$, and your inequality turns into approximately $\frac{1}{2n}\lVert y\rVert_2^2 \leq \frac{1}{2n}\lVert y-\mathbf{X}\theta^*\rVert_2^2$.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus the inequality does indeed hold and it is the consequence of the M-estimators (p. 212 Martin Wainwright's High-Dimensional Statistics). The norm is an $\ell_2$ Euclidean norm.

Comment: Counterexample: Say we have a sample of size 1 and the model is only the mean/intercept $Y_1 = \theta^\star + \epsilon_1$. Imagine that we have $\theta^\star = 1000$, we observe $Y_1 = 1004.2$ and $R=1$ then we have $$\frac{1}{2n}\lVert y-\mathbf{X}\hat{\theta}\rVert_2^2 =0.5(1004.2-1)^2$$ and this is not smaller than $$\frac{1}{2n}\lVert y-\mathbf{X}\theta^*\rVert_2^2 = 0.5(1004.2-1000)^2$$

Comment: Maybe it breaks down because the lasso regression is not an M-estimator. It has an additional penalty term.